# LTI system $y(t)=x(t-T)$ with or without memory

Tags: linear-systems, homework, delay

How can I verify if the LTI system ($T$ is a real number, $y(t)$ output, $x(t)$ input):

$$y(t)=x(t-T)$$

is with or without memory? I know that, if $y(t)$ depends only on $x(t)$, the LTI system will be without memory. In the above example, does it depend on $t-T$ or only on $t$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From Signals and Systems/Time Domain Analysis -- Memory](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Signals_and_Systems/Time_Domain_Analysis#Memory)

> A system is said to have memory if the output from the system is
>   dependent on past inputs (or future inputs) to the system. A system is
>   called memoryless if the output is only dependent on the current
>   input.

According to some textbooks, the notion of memory is stricter, and requires causality of the system. To that respect:

- if $T\ge 0$, the system is causal. If $T=0$, it only use the current time (**memoryless**).   If $T>0$, the output need a memory of the past of input $x$
- if $T< 0$, the system is non-causal.  The output needed a memory of the future of input $x$. You can either say "non applicable", or still term it "memory".

References (especially the first, with many practical exemples):

- [Lecture III: Systems and their properties](http://maxim.ece.illinois.edu/teaching/fall08/lec3.pdf) by Maxim Raginsky
- [$y(n)=x(-n)$, causal or not, memory or memoryless?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152684/yn-x-n-causal-or-not-memory-or-memoryless)

Comment: Hi @LaurentDuval. Sorry I did a mistake, now I'm editing the question.

Comment: maybe do you want to say that if $T<0$ the system is non-causal because $y(t=0)=x(-T>0)$?

Comment: Indeed, typed too fast